# Making an api call inside a loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loops

I am trying to scan the top 100 movie torrents on the pirate bay using node and add a movie poster for each result.

I am using these libraries

[thepiratebay](https://github.com/t3chnoboy/thepiratebay)
[imdb-api](https://github.com/worr/node-imdb-api)

I am able to find top 100 and return the results with no problems

```
app.get('/movies', function(req, res){
 tpb.topTorrents(207).then(function(topMovies){
    async.map(topMovies, tpb.getTorrent, function(err, results){
        res.send(results);
    })
 })
});
```

I am also able to look up movies via an IMDB ID and return the results

```
app.get('/imdb', function(req, res){
 imdb.getReq({ id: 'tt2660888' }, function(err, things) {
    res.send(things);
 });
});
```

What I am trying to do is loop over the top 100 results pull the imdb id out of the description field out and query imdb replacing the picture field with result.

```
app.get('/movies', function(req, res){
 tpb.topTorrents(207).then(function(topMovies){
     async.map(topMovies, tpb.getTorrent, function(err, results){
         for (var value of results) {
             if (S(value.description).contains('www.imdb.com/title/')) {
                 var imdbId = S(value.description).between('www.imdb.com/title/', '/').s
                     imdb.getReq({ id: imdbId }, function(err, movie) {
                         value["picture"] = movie.poster
                     });
             }
         }
         res.send(results);
     })
 })
});
```

This isn't working for some reason but it makes sense to me intuitively. If I remove the imdb-api call and replace it with value["picture"] = "foo". It does work. I'm not sure if this is related to how node handles loops. I'm new to the JS world and have a ruby background

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Pirate Bay is down, so scraping it right now probably isn't going to work.

Comment: No it's not. My problem isn't with tpb anyways

Comment: It's not clear what all those functions are, it's not even clear what `async` is, but I'm assuming it's the usual async middleware. Anyway `imdb.getReq()` is asynchronous, and you're probably getting the images, but `res.send()` happens long before that, probably before you even get the first response back from IMDB and replace the first image.

Comment: Your for-loop is not a sync call as it is written. So res.send is reached before you actually modify the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the async module but the imdb requests are also asynchronous so `res.send` just gets called with the initial result of `async.map`

You can use another `async.map` for the imdb calls and them chain them with `async.waterfall` which will pass the results of the first function as an argument to the second (`async.apply` just invokes the tpb function with your `topMovies`).

```
function tpb (topMovies, done) {
    async.map(topMovies, tpb.getTorrent, done);
}

function imdb (movies, done) {
    function lookup (value, callback) {
        if (S(value.description).contains('www.imdb.com/title/')) {
            var imdbId = S(value.description).between('www.imdb.com/title/', '/').s
            imdb.getReq({ id: imdbId }, function(err, movie) {
                value["picture"] = movie.poster
                return cb(err, value);
            });
        } else {
            return callback(null);
        }
    }

    async.map(movies, lookup, done);
}

app.get('/movies', function(req, res){
    tpb.topTorrents(207).then(function(topMovies){
        async.waterfall([async.apply(tpb, topMovies), imdb], function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                // do error handling
            }
            return res.send(results);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help but this doesn't work for me. I get no response from it